# Tomar resultado Print y ejecutar programa

Tags: python, python-3.x

Cuento con código que me permite buscar la ruta de un archivo dentro del sistema, más lo que necesito es **tomar la ruta que imprime** para poder ejecutar el programa de forma automática, es decir si el usuario no tiene el programa instalado en la ruta por defecto, el programa debe buscar la ruta, imprimirla y luego con el resultado abrir el programa.

Este es el código que tengo:

```
def buscararchivo():
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk("c:\\"):
        for files in files:
             if files == "WINWORD.EXE":
                  print (os.path.join(root,files))
                  quit()`
```

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que lo que preguntas es cómo lograr que, tecleando algo en una terminal de windows, el resultado sea que se ejecute WINWORD.EXE, para lo cual tu script lo busca en todo el sistema de archivos y necesitas cómo conectar el resultado con la interfaz de comandos.

El método que usas para encontrar WINWORD no me parece el más apropiado (una búsqueda recursiva por todas las carpetas del sistema puede llevar mucho tiempo, sería mejor restringir la búsqueda a algunas carpetas "sospechosas habituales" como `Program Files`). Pero dejando esto de lado, tienes dos alternativas:

- Si el comando lo lanzas desde una terminal que usa un shell tipo unix (por ejemplo una terminal de cygwin, o de Git-Bash), entonces puedes usar las capacidades de ese shell. Si, como parte de un comando del shell, encierras algo entre "backticks" (`` ` ``) lo que va dentro de ellos se ejecuta y lo que saldría por la salida estándar se usa como parte del comando en cuestión. Es un poco difícil de explicar, pero la idea sería:

  ```
  bash$ `python tu_script.py`
  ```

  (`bash$` es el prompt del sistema, no algo que tengas que teclear)
- Si el intérprete de comandos es el  `CMD` de windows, no conozco forma de hacer eso mismo, pero en este caso lo más sencillo es que tu propio script python lance el programa una vez encontrado, en lugar de mostrar por pantalla su ruta.

  Para esto basta cambiar el `print()` por `os.system()`

Comment: Mmmmmmm…primero quiero agradecer tu respuesta, pero lo que intento hacer, es que cuando el código antes mencionado me entregue la ruta de Word en este caso. es alguna función que me permita copiar el resultado de ese print y utilizarlo luego en una función como **os. startfile** y de esa forma sin importar donde esté instalado el programa poder iniciarlo.

Comment: el problema es que no puedo iniciar el programa con **os.startfile** sin tener la ruta del mismo, es por eso que necesito copiar el resultado de la ruta

Comment: Pero... no acabo de entender. Mencionas `os.startfile()`, pero esa debería recibir como argumento un fichero `.docx` y (a través de las asociaciones de Windows) determinaría que el programa a ejecutar es WINWORD. Pero en tu caso ya has encontrado el ejecutable por lo que la función a usar sería más bien `os.system()` (a la que le pasas como parámetro el comando a ejecutar, que sería la ruta a word más el documento a abrir, caso de que quieras abrir uno)

Comment: Tienes toda la razón….
Fue mi error ….
Muchísimas gracias por responder y por la disposición de ayudar: D

Answer (score 0):

Una observación primero, no debes hacer `for files in files:`, cómo mínimo es confuso, en su lugar puedes hacer `for file in files:`.

En cuanto a tu problema, si quieres lanzar "WINWORD.EXE" cuando sea encontrado en el sistema de archivos puedes hacer que se ejecute en un nuevo proceso usando `os.startfile` sin problemas como comentas:

```
import os

def buscar_y_ejecutar():
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk("c:/"):
        for file in files:
             if file == "WINWORD.EXE":
                 path = os.path.join(root, file)
                 os.startfile(path)
                 quit()


buscar_y_ejecutar()
```

O vía [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) si quieres más control sobre el proceso desde el script de Python (paso de parámetros, redirección de *stdin*/*stdout*/*stderr*, confirmación de finalización, etc):

```
import subprocess

def buscar_y_ejecutar():
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk("c:/"):
        for file in files:
             if file == "WINWORD.EXE":
                 path = os.path.join(root, file)
                 subprocess.run([path])
                 quit()

buscar_y_ejecutar()
```

Puedes pasar argumentos si el ejecutable los necesita o acepta sin problemas, por ejemplo:

```
subprocess.run(["c:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe",
                "www.google.com",
                "es.stackoverflow.com"])
```

Si quieres abrir un archivo con el programa predeterminado por el sistema en Windows puedes hacer simplemente:

```
path = "D:/Documentos/archivo.docx"
os.startfile(path)
```

Lo que debe abrir el fichero *archivo.docx* con la aplicación predeterminada, por ejemplo M.Word.

Comment: Totalmente, Muchas gracias @fjsevilla